# Clean up changes after aborting gulp watch task

Tags: gulp

I have a npm script for development that includes a [gulp watch](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files) task:

`package.json`:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp setupStyles && gulp watch && <other-task>",
  },
...
```

This works pretty well for my use case. However, the script starts with `gulp setupStyles` which changes some files just for development.

How can I run a task that would revert the changes made by `gulp setupStyles`? Basically how can I trigger a function/gulp-task when the watch task stops (usually by pressing `Ctrl + C` in the terminal or by an error in the script)?

Comment: there's event options in `gulp.watch()` https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/

Comment: I saw that and I tried setting up a watch task with `{ events: ['error'] }`, but that does not get triggered when I abort with `Ctrl + C`, which is 90% of when I need it

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, I believe that's not how it works.
You might try to **dest** your output into another folder other than your main **app** folder, that way you will always keep your main workshop files intact.

you might find this [gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate) usfule

Comment: Thanks, that is what I normally do. In this case I need to edit a file that is generated by a build upstream build process that I have no control over.